# Calculate date difference in months when format is Month YYYY

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have stored a date in two columns like :

```
from          |   to
----------------------
January 2012  | March 2013    
July 2011     | June 2013
```

How can I get the difference in between these two dates in months?

I want the output as **15** for first row and **11** for second row

Comment: That's not really a good way to store a date when you want to do calculations with it. Why not use `DATETIME`?

Comment: why `11` on second row?

Comment: @JW Because he can't count without a query :) He probably means from July **2012** and the count should be **12**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use function [`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your strings to actual `DATE` type. After that, you can use [`period_diff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff) to compute difference in months, but you have to convert your date using [`date_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) into format that is supported by `period_diff` (which is confusingly is NOT a date).

Final SQL is ([SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6993e/1)):

```
SELECT period_diff(
    date_format(str_to_date(`to`,   '%M %Y'), '%Y%m'),
    date_format(str_to_date(`from`, '%M %Y'), '%Y%m'))
FROM mytable
```

One note though: I don't quite understand where did you get **15** and **11** from. This query gives difference between `from` and `to` in months, and for your data it is `14` and `23` respectively. Just to demonstrate, I have also added current month as `from` and `to`, and it does indeed compute to 0 difference.